# x is not a function... but it is

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, redux

I am getting an error that "addCommentLike" is not a function, but the exact same code is working elsewhere in the app to like posts. I am trying to also be able to like comments but it keeps failing.

It is also weird that deleteComment has the darker text that means it is being called whereas addCommentLike and removeCommentLike both have the muted text color even though they both are being called. I'm guessing this is the problem but don't know how to fix it.

Thanks in advance!!

```
import {
  deleteComment,
  addCommentLike,
  removeCommentLike,
} from "../../actions/aquariums";

const CommentItem = ({
  aquaId,
  comment: { _id, name, text, avatar, user, date, rating, likes },
  auth,
  deleteComment,
  addCommentLike,
  removeCommentLike,
}) => {

  return (
          <button
            onClick={(e) => addCommentLike(_id)}
            type='button'
            className='btn btn-light'
          >
            <i className='fas fa-chevron-up'></i>{" "}
          </button>
          {likes.length > 0 && <span>{likes.length}</span>}
          <button
            onClick={(e) => removeCommentLike(_id)}
            type='button'
            className='btn btn-light'
          >
            <i className='fas fa-chevron-down'></i>
          </button>
          {!auth.loading && user === auth.user._id && (
            <button
              onClick={(e) => deleteComment(aquaId, _id)}
              type='button'
              className='btn btn-danger'
            >
              <i className='fas fa-times'></i>
            </button>
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

CommentItem.propTypes = {
  aquaId: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  comment: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  auth: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  deleteComment: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  addCommentLike: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  removeCommentLike: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  auth: state.auth,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { deleteComment })(CommentItem);
```

Comment: If you were using a rule like [ESLint's `no-shadow`](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-shadow), it would have help to find that you're shadowing the imports with the props and that fixing this shadowing would make it clear that the function wasn't used properly (like both answers have pointed out).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`addCommentLike` is an action that should be dispatched. Pass an object to `connect` function containing all your actions that you need to dispatch from current component

change

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, { deleteComment })(CommentItem);
```

to

```
export default connect(
   mapStateToProps,
   { deleteComment, addCommentLike, removeCommentLike }
)(CommentItem);
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like `addCommentLike` is a redux action. You have added `deleteComment` to the mapDispatchToProps, but not `addCommentLike` or `removeCommentLike`, so  they will be undefined.

Just add it to the object you already have in `connect` and it should work.

```js
export default connect(mapStateToProps, { deleteComment, addCommentLike, removeCommentLike })(CommentItem);
```